# Dyanamic library linking by RTLD_LAZY

Tags: c, linux, dynamic-linking

I am trying to find the differance between RTLD_NOW and RTLD_LAZY flags. My query is why RTLD_LAZY loading the library whose function I've never referanced.

I have created a dlrun.c file

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "dlfcn.h"

main()
{
  void * ptr;
  void (*fptr)(void);
  printf("\nMy ID is- %d \n",getpid());
  getchar();
  ptr = dlopen("./fun5.so", RTLD_NOW);
  if(ptr==NULL)
    printf("failed to open fun5.so");
  else
  {
    printf("I got fun5.so");
    fptr= dlsym(ptr,"fun5");
    getchar();
    fptr();
    printf("end of fun5");
    dlclose(ptr);
  }
}
```

the next file fun5.c as

```
#include "stdio.h"

void fun2(void);
void fun1(void);

fun5()
{
  printf("I am in fun5");
  getchar();
  fun1();
}

fun()
{
  getchar(); 
  fun2();
}
```

other file fun1.c is

```
#include "stdio.h"

fun1()
{
  printf("I am in fun1");
  getchar();
}
```

and file fun2.c is

```
#include "stdio.h"

fun2()
{
  printf("I am in fun2");
  getchar();
}
```

then I use commands

```
gcc -c -fPIC -o fun1.o fun1.c
gcc -c -fPIC -o fun2.o fun2.c
gcc -c -fPIC -o fun5.o fun5.c
gcc -shared -o fun1.so fun1.o
gcc -shared -o fun2.so fun2.o
gcc -shared -o fun5.so fun5.o ./fun1.so ./fun2.so
gcc dlrun.c -o run -ldl
./run
```

now I want to check which libraries are loaded by

```
cd /proc/<pid>
vi maps
```

Here it looks that before fun5.so calling no nonstansard libray is loaded and after calling fun5 function all fun5.so,fun1.so and fun.2.so are loaded as per expectation.Now if I replace RTLD_NOW by RTLD_LAZY then only fun5.so and fun1.so should be loaded because I have never called fun() and fun2() , but actually fun2.so is also loading.so where am I wrong? Am I wrong at creating fun5.so? if so then how should I create it?

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

The following example should make it very clear:

**libtest.so:**

```
void bar();

void foo()
{
    bar();
}
```

_

```
$> nm libtest.so
000085d0 a _DYNAMIC
000086b0 a _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
         w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
         w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
         w _Jv_RegisterClasses
000005c0 r __FRAME_END__
000085cc d __JCR_END__
000085cc d __JCR_LIST__
000086e0 d __TMC_END__
000086e4 B __bss_end__
000086e0 B __bss_start
000086e0 B __bss_start__
         w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.4
000004f8 t __do_global_dtors_aux
000085c8 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
000086dc d __dso_handle
000086e4 B __end__
000085c4 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
         w __gmon_start__
000086e4 B _bss_end__
000086e0 D _edata
000086e4 B _end
000005b8 T _fini
000003e0 T _init
         U bar
00000424 t call_weak_fn
000086e0 b completed.8847
00000448 t deregister_tm_clones
000005a8 T foo
00000560 t frame_dummy
0000049c t register_tm_clones
```

**main.c (flag == RTLD_LAZY):**

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *lib = dlopen("./libtest.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!lib) {
        printf("error: %s\n", dlerror());
        return 0;
    }
    int (*a)() = dlsym(lib, "foo");
    printf("a: %p\n", a);
    (*a)();

    dlclose(lib);
    return 1;
}

$> ./main.c
a: 0xb6e225a8
./main: symbol lookup error: ./libtest.so: undefined symbol: bar
```

**main.c (flag == RTLD_NOW):**

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *lib = dlopen("./libtest.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (!lib) {
        printf("error: %s\n", dlerror());
        return 0;
    }
    int (*a)() = dlsym(lib, "foo");
    printf("a: %p\n", a);
    (*a)();

    dlclose(lib);
    return 1;
}
$> ./main.c
error: ./libtest.so: undefined symbol: bar
```

Comment: your example actually shows, there will always be difference between knowing the thing & explaining the thing to the unknown.  Even though, I was aware of the difference, this example is just superb!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

`RTLD_LAZY` actually means resolve symbols lazily, not load libraries lazily. `fun5.so` depends on both of these libraries so they will be loaded when `fun5.so` is loaded.

The line:

```
gcc -shared -o fun5.so fun5.o ./fun1.so ./fun2.so
```

tells us that `fun5.so` explicitly depends on `fun1.so` and `fun2.so`, which is why you're seeing this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
but as per the man page RTLD_LAZY Only resolve symbols as the code that references them is executed and I've never called fun() or fun2() to execute.In fun5.c I've only defined those function and never called.

Comment: Ok now I changed fun5 as

    fun5()
    {
    void * ptr = NULL;
    void (*fptr)(void);
    printf("I am in fun5");
    getchar();
    ptr=dlopen("./fun2.so",RTLD_LAZY);
    printf("fun2.so called to open");
    getchar();
    ptr=dlopen("./fun1.so",RTLD_LAZY);
    fptr=dlsym(ptr,"fun1");
    fptr();
    }

Comment: and I created shared object by
gcc -c -fPIC -o fun5.o fun5.c
gcc -shared -o fun5.so fun5.o

(In main function also I was using RTLD_LAZY flag)
here I've not called function in fun2.so but still it is loading fun1.so, fun2.so and fun5.so.

If I am wrong somewhere then please suggest how should I check diff between use of RTLD_NOW & _LAZY.

Answer (score 0):

Following the "fliX", example your can see the nm gives :

```
     U bar
```

and we get the unresolved error accordingly.

Hence, You call a function or you don't, a library, when loading cannot be loaded if it has some Undefined Symbol. Hence, even if it is a dead code at certain point, it shall be to be resolved at the time of loading, because the PROCESSOR instruction will be unknown when that symbol hits.